# How to fix 'command not found' error in Databricks when creating a secret scope

Tags: databricks, secret-key

I am trying to create a secret scope in a Databricks notebook. The notebook is running using a cluster created by my company's admin - I don't have access to create or edit clusters. I'm following the instructions in the Databricks user notebooks (https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/secrets/example-secret-workflow.html#example-secret-workflow) but get an error:

```
/bin/bash: databricks: command not found
```

Below is the code I've tried that returns the error:

```
%sh -e
databricks secrets create-scope --scope scopename
```

sh% is used so I can run the command line language in the notebook. I've tried using

```
%sh
```

and also

```
%sh -e
```

no luck.

I should be able to create a secret scope using this code but have had no luck. Any suggestions on the cause of this? Has anyone else had the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not heard of running the CLI from the cluster before. Even if it is installed I doubt it is configured.
You can download the CLI and run it from your local machine: https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dev-tools/databricks-cli.html

You will need to be running Python locally. If you prefer there is also a PowerShell command-line (disclaimer I produced this): https://github.com/DataThirstLtd/azure.databricks.cicd.tools

Answer (score 4):

Databricks clusters don't have databricks-cli installed by default. That doesn't mean you can't install it on the cluster. You can install databricks-cli using the following command in any databricks notebook:

```
%sh
/databricks/python/bin/pip install databricks-cli==0.9.1
```

Logging in may be a problem as you can't send responses using shell scripts within the notebooks. You can create the *.databrickscfg* file in the clusters root directory using the following set of commmands:

```
%sh
> ~/.databrickscfg
echo "[DEFAULT]" >> ~/.databrickscfg
echo "host = <your host>" >> ~/.databrickscfg
echo "token = <your token>" >> ~/.databrickscfg
```

You can save these commands as shell scripts that can be run automatically on cluster start up ([init scripts](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/init-scripts.html)).

Comment: Your line, "echo "host = <your host>" >> ~/,databrickscfg" has a comma "," before databrickscfg instead of a period.

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue with notebook.

If you have to run any **databricks cli commands** on your databricks instance, easiest way should be to use **Web terminal**.
You can launch web terminal from *compute->Clusters->Apps->Launch Web Terminal*

- If not installed , you can use **pip install databricks-cli**
- Configure user through command **databricks configure** or **databricks
  configure --token**

Now you are good to run databricks cli commands
Here's a sample run on databricks web terminal which worked for me:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One other reason the ( /bin/bash: databricks: command not found) can happen that I noticed on my mac that is not listed here is the user path not exported. add this to your bash profile file or just run the command : export PATH="......(path to your python library)/Library/Python/3.9/bin"

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the winner for this topic but it came up for me and this was top contender for my solution. I had an issue where I got `Error: No such command 'secrets\xa0put'.` This was caused due to having NSBP characters between my parameters in `databricks secrets put --scope ...`